# force:org:list not returning correct information

Tags: salesforcedx

I accidentally authenticated to a developer edition as my default dev hub and it messed up my list of orgs. I logged out of all orgs in sfdx and re-logged in with the correct org as my dev hub. I've also connected to a few sandboxes. Now when I `force:org:list` it shows undefined.

[image: listing]

What us odd is if I go to set a default for my project in vs code, I can see the orgs I'm logged into:

[image: vs code]

I'm on `sfdx-cli/7.42.1-e41dbeb8d9 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3`

Comment: What version of sfdx cli you are on ?

Comment: Can you `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` and see if there's any errors there?

Comment: Updated question with my version. And no errors are showing in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have fixed the problem by uninstalling the salesforcedx plugin and then reinstalling it.

`sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx`

`sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest`

Comment: An sfdx update might have also fixed it I guess.Looks like you have older version

Comment: I had run `sfdx update` first and it didn't make a difference.